# User attribute "Enabled" is blank for some disabled users in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I was trying to list active and disabled users in AD using powershell commands.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT samaccountname
```

But the list was incorrectly populated. Some of the disabled users were listed in active user list.

When I checked those users' attributes, I found that the "Enabled" attribute is blank for those users. It was neither true nor false.

Please advise on how to update their attributes.

Comment: Check the other way around `Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -ne $true}`

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old question, but answering it for others who search for it.

I ran into this same issue, running the command with a domain admin account, about half the accounts were coming back with both the userAccountControl and Enabled coming back as blank, but using ADUC, I could view the userAccountControl on the attributes tab.

I can't explain the reasoning, but running powershell as administrator resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always with AD filters you want to enclose variables like `$false` or `$true` in quotes.

Try this, open powershell and runas administrator then use the following:

`Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $false' | ft samaccountname,enabled`

Your domain account may not have read permissions on userAccountControl.

Answer (score 0):

Run the powershell console elevated (as Administrator).